# Android Service has leaked even though it is (supposedly) not running

Tags: android, android-service

in `onDestroy()` I check whether the service is still running using the code below. If it is - I unbind and stop it.

```
public boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        String serviceClassName = serviceClass.getName();
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for(RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services){
            if(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now I have a situation when `isServiceRunning` returns false, but after `onDestroy()` I get an error saying that ServiceConnection has leaked. Why would that be?

**Edit**:

That's how I start the `Service` (in `onCreate()`):

```
startService(posServiceIntent);
bindService(posServiceIntent, posConn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and

```
posServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PositionService.class);

private ServiceConnection posConn = new PosServiceConnection();
public class PosServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.d(TAG, "PosServiceBinder connected [name: " + name.toShortString() + "].");
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.d(TAG, "PosServiceBinder disconnected [name: " + name.toShortString() + "].");
        }
    }

protected void onDestroy() {
        if(isServiceRunning(PositionService.class)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping PositionService in " + MainActivity.class.getSimpleName() + ".onDestroy()");
            unbindService(posConn);
            stopService(posServiceIntent);
        }
```

Comment: How do you instantiate the Service? Could you paste that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `unbindService()` in `onDestroy()`. Stopping the service won't make it stop if it has bound connections.

In any case, the error "ServiceConnection leaked" appears because you still have a bound connection to the service.

**EDIT: Add additional observation**

You wrote:

> "I check whether the service is still running using the code below. If
>   it is - I unbind and stop it"

That won't prevent leaking the `ServiceConnection`. You need to call `unbindService()` when your activity shuts down even if your service is no longer running. Make sure to put the call to `unbindService()` in a try/catch block because it is posible to get an `IllegalArgumentException` which you can safely ignore (it means you have no connection to the service).

Comment: Correct. A Bound Service has to be unbound when the Activity is destroyed. It sounds logical when you read it like this, eh?

Comment: @tolgap alright I fixed the question as it's wasn't clear when you read it, that I stop **and** unbind the service.

Comment: I added more details to my answer, have a look.

Comment: Please make sure that you call `unbindService()` unconditionally in `onDestroy()`. Don't put it inside the `if (isServiceRunning())` condition.